# Boot animation upside down after new ROM

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, custom-roms, bugs, debug

I have a **Wileyfox Spark**, for lovers of it, you surely know it comes with **CyanogenMod13** **OS** as it's stock. But you know very well how one might want a more decent **Nougat** or **Oreo** based **CM14** or **CM15** or even **AOSP7.x.x**. I have all the ROMs I need in the device and a ready **TWRP 3.2.0**, a full backup of the stock images from **boot.img** to **userdata.img**. Installing the new ROMs work fine despite the fact that on any **custom OS** I have tried, the device boot's up with the boot animation **180° rotated**. This continues to bootup and it only returns normal if I turn display off and on. Flashing the **stock boot.img** solves the issue of rotation but since the ROM isn't stock, it just **Bootloops** infinitely. I'm not a **Kernel developer** and neither do I have enough knowledge on how to do. I suggest somebody with a **workaround** for this issue. I don't like the **stock OS** which I'm forced to return to.

Comment: So what is your question here? As this site focuses on end-users, development questions are off-topic here. Have you considered asking the ROM developers in the forums where you downloaded those ROMs?

Comment: I'm looking for an alternative way to deal with this locally, not through redevelopment. That's why I said I need a 'workaround' since all ROMs behave so, it seems like a local issue because all developers won't be making a similar error you know. I have tried more than 10 different developer's works. So it seems something associated with TWRP, Phone or Some phone thing should be addressed

Comment: Ah, OK. In that case I'd say: closing the eyes for a little while would be the easiest work-around – or do you boot that often so it really hurts that much? Afraid from the user's end there's not much else that could be done. But well, I might learn otherwise (wouldn't be the first time I got a surprise here :) Good luck then! // PS: Might well be Wileyfox incidentally put the logo upside-down and has their boot-code flipping it – just to see if a device to be serviced was tampered with? #D

Comment: Okay. Some people don't like living with a bug they know it exists like me. If perfection is not attained I don't, for example seem to live up. That's why imma be curious. Closing an eye is not closing your mind. Just an example: If you have a serious ailment and the doctor shows you to assume you're well, will you take that and be normal?

Comment: No offense was meant, sorry if I sounded rude! Just saying it might be the only thing left – while still hoping someone comes up with something better.

Comment: If you want to make it so the upside-down display problem isn't there to begin with, sorry, that's up to the ROM dev. But if you can bear with having to turn screen off/on once the device had booted up, and just want the bootanimation to look normal, well that's quite easy, just edit the bootanimation itself to make it upside-down. If that's what you're looking for, I'll post a simple answer.

Comment: No problem I never meant you were rude Izzy I was just straight talking. Yeah as a matter of fact since all ROMs behave so except the stock firm, I'm starting to believe maybe that might be triggered by the system. Thanks AndyYan too For that answer too. I never even thought about that, Thanks for that a lot. I will be happy to hear from all you guys again. Cheers

Comment: So what's your response to my last comment - are you satisfied with just having the bootanimation rotated? If yes, just grab `/system/media/bootanimation.zip`, extract it and rotate every image file in it. If you're interested I can either post an answer about it or simply do it for you if you send the file over.

Comment: @AndyYan Post that. It's the only option it seems I got. Tried it out and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can bear with having to turn screen off/on once the device had booted up, and just want the bootanimation to look normal, that's quite easy - just edit the bootanimation itself to make it upside-down.

- Grab and extract `/system/media/bootanimation.zip`.
- Rotate every extracted image by 180 degrees.
- Recompress the extracted files, keep the structure (compare with the original if necessary), and choose "storage" when asked about compression level (any actual compression will prevent Android from reading the file).
- Place the modified file back to where it was and set proper permissions.